# Convert DateTime Column Format in DataSet from US/UK to US

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

How can I optimize below method which convert DataSet DateTime Column from US/UK format to US Format. The initial Date Format can be US/UK or any other country. Need to convert that to US Date Format in the output DataSet

```
private DataSet ModifyDateToUSFormat(DataSet ds)
    {
        DataSet dsRes = new DataSet();
        DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;

        //Convert from DateTime to String Type
        DataTable dtCloned = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                dtCloned.Columns[dc.ColumnName].DataType = typeof(string);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            dtCloned.ImportRow(row);

        //Change the String format to US format. Since Database expects US Format Only.
        foreach (DataRow row in dtCloned.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                    row[dc.ColumnName] = DateTime.Parse(row[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault).ToString(usDtfi.ShortDatePattern);
            }
        }

        dsRes.Tables.Add(dtCloned);
        return dsRes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the very problem you are attempting to solve.

A `DateTime` does not carry *any* culture info or particular format.  Neither do date and time data types in a database, such as `datetime` in SQL Server.

When you convert it from `DateTime` to `string` - that's when you're using the culture info to apply a format.  Then you are trying to use a different culture to parse the string in a different format and parse it back to a `DateTime`, where again it has no culture info.

The simple answer then is - *don't do this*.

To make it very clear - when you see output from your database in either SQL Management Studio, Visual Studio Debugger, or whatever environment you are using - that's not a `DateTime`.  That's the `string` *representation* of the `DateTime`.  Wherever you are looking will apply the current culture when you *view* it.  It doesn't actually exist in the database in that format.

For example, in SQL Server, a `datetime` field is stored as 8 bytes.  Consider:

```
-- implicitly convert to varchar using the current culture info
select getdate()    -- outputs:  2013-08-19 15:38:41.503

-- explicity convert to varchar using the current culture info
select convert(varchar, getdate())    -- outputs: Aug 19 2013  3:38PM

-- explicity convert to varbinary to show how it's really stored
select convert(varbinary, getdate())  -- outputs:  0x0000A21F0101D1C3
```

Comment: Thx Matt for your help. Modified above function as below

`private DataSet ModifyDateToUSFormat(DataSet ds)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                    dc.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified;
            }
            return ds;
        }`

Comment: That's a different concept entirely. You will probably find that the setting is *already* `Unspecified` - or more likely `UnspecifiedLocal` - but that's not going to matter here.  You should focus your efforts not on manipulating the dataset, but on wherever the dataset is finally output.